# How to remove numbers from string terms in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a data frame similar to the one below:

```
Name    Volume  Value
May21   23      21321
James   12      12311
Adi22   11      4435
Hello   34      32454
Girl90  56      654654
```

I want the output to be in the format:

```
Name    Volume  Value
May     23      21321
James   12      12311
Adi     11      4435
Hello   34      32454
Girl    56      654654
```

Want to remove all the numbers from the Name column.

Closest I have come is doing it at a **cell** level with the following code:

```
result = ''.join([i for i in df['Name'][1] if not i.isdigit()])
```

Any idea how to  do it in a better way at the **series**/**dataframe** level.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can apply [str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to the `Name` column in combination with regular expressions:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name'  : ['May21', 'James', 'Adi22', 'Hello', 'Girl90'],
                             'Volume': [23, 12, 11, 34, 56],
                             'Value' : [21321, 12311, 4435, 32454, 654654]})

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\d+', '')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name   Value  Volume
0    May   21321      23
1  James   12311      12
2    Adi    4435      11
3  Hello   32454      34
4   Girl  654654      56
```

In the regular expression `\d` stands for "any digit" and `+` stands for "one or more".

Thus, `str.replace('\d+', '')` means: "Replace all occurring digits in the strings with nothing".

Answer (score 22):

You can do it like so:

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('\d+', '')
```

To play and explore, check the online Regular expression demo here: https://regex101.com/r/Y6gJny/2

Whatever is matched by the pattern `\d+` i.e 1 or more digits, will be replaced by empty string.

Answer (score 17):

`.str` is not necessary. You can use pandas [dataframe.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) or [series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True` argument.

```
df.replace('\d+', '', regex=True)
```

if you want to change source dataframe use `inplace=True`.

```
df.replace('\d+', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can we use this to remove bad data such theres space between the numeric value? ie. "12  445"

Answer (score 10):

Although the question sounds more general, the example input only contains *trailing* numbers. In this case you don't have to use regular expressions, since [`.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) (also available [via the `.str` accessor of `Series` objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)) can do exactly this:

```
import string
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.rstrip(string.digits)
```

Similarly, you can use [`.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html#pandas.Series.str.lstrip) to strip any digits from the start, or [`.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html#pandas.Series.str.strip) to remove any digits from the start and the end of each string.