# Pandas way of splitting a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe where I wish to change entries in country column, eg:

*'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia'*,

*'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'*

I have defined the following function:

```
def process(w):
    for i in range(len(w)):
        if w[i] in ['(', ')', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '&', '/']:
            w = w[0:i]
            w = ''.join(w).replace(" ", "")
            break

    return w
```

which I have then applied to the dataframe using the python **apply** function.

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].apply(process)
```

While I have been able to achieve the desired output, it is not entirely correct. Some entries like

*United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland* and *United States of America20* have changed to 
*UnitedKingdomofGreatBritainandNorthernIreland* and *UnitedStatesofAmerica* .

What am I doing wrong? Also what would be a more effective, concise code to achieve the result?

Comment: you want to remove integer part from country name or something else?

Comment: @Shubham Gupta, the honor code https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/209818863-Coursera-Honor-Code states `Your answers to homework, quizzes, and exams must be your own work`

Comment: These links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719259/pandas-dataframe-how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-terms-in-a-dataframe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894525/how-to-remove-parentheses-and-all-data-within-using-pandas-python will help you part way. Can can work with them.

Comment: `a=''.join([i for i in a if i.isalpha()])` use this statement for doing this.

Comment: @Dark, of course I would submit my own work. I was just wondering if someone could point me towards a solution better than my obviously primitive one. Thank you for the links though!

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey, I already did that. Doesn't get the desired result. Bolivia (Plurinational State of) changes to BoliviaPlurinationalStateof. Although I could work with this, it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: Please specify some of the test case in your problem statement for more clarification?

Comment: @Dark, is there way I can pass a more general list of characters instead of doing them individually?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta its called regex. Try to look at some regex examples

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something, but it looks like

```
replace(" ", "")
```

is going to remove spaces, which is exactly what is happening with UnitedStatesofAmerica

Comment: ```pd.replace``` also has a ```regex=False``` (default) flag using which you can directly replace the values instead of the looping through the values.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the case. Another question though, American Samoa was not returned as AmericanSamoa (and many similar to it) but United States of America was. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: My guess is that if American Samoa had no numbers of characters in it then , it wouldn't have triggered the If statement, so it would have never gone into that loop. 

If you found my answer useful, please click on the upward triangle next to my answer. It will give me points.