# Pandas - substring each row with a different length

Tags: python, string, pandas, slice

Good day,

I have a dataframe where I want to isolate a part of the string for each row for that column. The problem I am having is that each row needs to have a substring of a different length, specifically I want to keep the string only up until the first occurs of "." (a period) **plus the next two letters**.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

x = [ [ 34, 'Sydney.Au123XX'] ,
             [30, 'Delhi.As1q' ] ,
             [16, 'New York.US3qqa']]
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x.columns = ["a", "b"]

#now I want to substring each row based on where "." occurs.
#I have tried the following:
y = x["b"].str.slice( stop = x["b"].str.find(".") + 2)
y = x["b"].str[0: x["b"].str.find(".")+ 2]

#desired output
desired = [[ 34, 'Sydney.Au'] ,
             [30, 'Delhi.As' ] ,
             [16, 'New York.US'] ]
desired  = pd.DataFrame(desired )
desired .columns = ["a", "b"]
```

Please see my code for the desired output.

I do not want to use a loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does New York have stuff after the `.`

Comment: @U10-Forward. Thank you, I did see your answer, and it was correct for the first version of my question. Please see updates to my question. Can str.split() work for the case where I wish to keep the first two characters after the "." as well?

Comment: @U10-Forward. I think for my revised question I could keep  x['b'].str.split('.').str[1] to keep the first two letters after ".". Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove numbers from string terms in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719259/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-terms-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC try:

```
x['b'] = x['b'].str.split('.').str[0]
print(x)
```

Also you can do an one-liner:

```
print(x.assign(b=x['b'].str.split('.').str[0]))
```

They both output:

```
    a         b
0  34    Sydney
1  30     Delhi
2  16  New York
```

**Edit:**

Do:

```
x['b'] = x['b'].str.extract('(.*\...)')
print(x)
```

Or use:

```
print(x.assign(b=x['b'].str.extract('(.*\...)')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

x = [ [ 34, 'Sydney.Au123'] ,
             [30, 'Delhi.As1' ] ,
             [16, 'New York.US3']]

data = [["{0}.{1}".format(i.split(".")[0],i.split(".")[1][0:2]) if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in y] for y in x ]
df  = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
    a            b
0  34    Sydney.Au
1  30     Delhi.As
2  16  New York.US
```