# Renaming column name based on its value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

```
df 

col_1    col_2     col_3
min1     max1     target1
min2     max2     target2
```

I would like to rename columns col_1, col_2, col_3 based on their value as Min, Max, and Target respectively. I would like to have something below as a result.

```
Min     Max     Target
min1    max1    target1
min2    max2    target2
```

Can anyone show me a simple trick to do this using Pandas python?

Comment: What do you mean by *"based on their value"* ? @Kapital

Comment: Is not possible set `df.columns = ['Min','Max','Target']` ?

Comment: For example, for col_0 it has value min1 and min2. Based on this min1 and min2 value rename the column as Min. Since it has those names under it.

Comment: @jezrael My Table is really big and I would like to create a rule to do that. In your case, it was simple.

Comment: @Kapital - OK, but how is possible distinguish what column is filled by minimal values, what column by maximal, what column is filled by target? Is possible explain more?

Comment: What happens if `col_1` has `min1` and `max1`?

Comment: @Vishnudev In my case, col_1 don't have both of them. But what if we create a rule? Something like if the data frame columns have the word ```min``` inside it rename the column as a "Min" whatever value inside it?

Comment: It's not a good practise to depend on the values for columns because it might cause inconsistency in further code. You won't be sure of the column names. Suppose there is a column with value `target1start1` what would you rename it as? `target` or `target1` or `targetstart`.

Comment: @Kapital - Are you sure not exist 2 columns with `min` substring?

Comment: @Vishnudev Is that possible to do some regular expression for that to extract the word target only whatever the combination of words we have?

Comment: @jezrael You said it is duplicate and you provided me a link on top of my post but my question and the solution you provided me are completely different. I saw that solution before I post this question. Could you please remove that?

Comment: So u wanted MAX of the column max. And likewise for the column min.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not sure that you **should** rename columns this way, but here is a way you **could** do it. First [remove numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719259/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-terms-in-a-pandas-dataframe) and then use the [most common string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950650/how-to-sort-counter-by-value-python).

```
from collections import Counter

cols = [Counter(df[col].str.replace('\d+', '')).most_common()[0][0].capitalize()
        for col in df.columns
        ]

df.columns = cols
```

Output:

```
    Min     Max     Target
0   min1    max1    target1
1   min2    max2    target2
```